# What is the best implememtation of react shouldComponentUpdate with immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm new to [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). My app implements large Redux Store & multiple react components.

Correct me if I'm wrong:

- I understand that the benefits of Immutable is to protect Flux Store and to avoid unnecessary vDom rendering on component getting unchanged props.
- To benefit from better rendering performance with ImmutableJS, `shouldComponentUpdate()` must be implemented.

What is the best implementation of this function?

I already found several implementations of it, all using shallowEqual() with some modifications:

- Facebook implements [shallowEqual](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/src/core/shallowEqual.js) for React and more I imagine.
- Jurassix offers [an implementation](https://github.com/jurassix/react-immutable-render-mixin) that implements [shallowEqualImmutable](https://github.com/jurassix/react-immutable-render-mixin/blob/master/src/shallowEqualImmutable.js). It the function from Facebook except that the `is()` function is replaced by the one given by ImmutableJS. The first equality is different too.
- Dan does the same thing with a [different shalllowEqual function](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js) that implement parts of the two previous implementation.

Someone knows which implementation I should use in my case? or none and implement specific `shouldComponentUpdate()`? I am slightly at a loss on this point

Thank you a lot for any help!!

Comment: Have you looked at PureRenderMixin? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html This also makes a shallow comparison, but with ImmutableJs that is sufficient.

Comment: Yes PureRenderMixin actually call `shallowEqual` from Facebook. it is the first point I mention. What do you mean by "it is sufficient"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that the benefits of Immutable is to protect Flux Store and to avoid unnecessary vDom rendering on component getting unchanged props.

This is not really related to Immutable (if you mean the library). For example, you can use plain objects and arrays with Redux but since Redux asks you to never mutate them, you get pretty much the same benefits in most cases. So Immutable library can offer a nicer API for updating things immutably, but it is not required for performance optimizations if you don’t mutate plain objects or arrays.

> To benefit from better rendering performance with ImmutableJS, shouldComponentUpdate() must be implemented.

Again, not really related to ImmutableJS, but yes, to benefit from immutability in props, you’d need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`. However if you use Redux you probably already use `connect()` from React Redux package which implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` for you for most cases. So you don’t really need to write it by hand for any `connect()` ed components.

> Someone knows which implementation I should use in my case? or none and implement specific shouldComponentUpdate()? I am slightly at a loss on this point

If you don’t have performance problems, don’t use either. React by itself is fairly performant in most cases, and a `connect()` on top of it will add a good default implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

For components that are not `connect()`ed but still get frequently updated, I would suggest you to use [`react-addons-shallow-compare`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html). It is used by `PureRenderMixin` internally but since mixins are not really used in modern React APIs, a separate function can be more convenient.

If you want special support for `Immutable.is`, you can indeed use something like [`shallowEqualImmutable`](https://github.com/jurassix/react-immutable-render-mixin/blob/master/src/shallowEqualImmutable.js). It understands Immutable collections better, as it considers lists of the same values to be the same. At this point you would be better off profiling different implementations against your app, as the specifics can vary depending on your use case.

Don’t optimize prematurely, make sure this is an actual problem before solving it.

Comment: You've also got [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#pure)'s implementations (`pure`, `onlyUpdateForKeys`, `onlyUpdateForPropTypes`) that allow you to use Higher-order Components so that you can keep your code in the stateless functional component syntax.

Comment: @Dan, Thank you a lot for the details. I understand that `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `ImmutableJS` are two entirely different things. It is considering both concepts together that loose me somehow. But I think your answer help a lot. You make me realize that `shouldComponentUpdate()` should use `react-addons-shallow-compare` for mutable props and  `shallowEqualImmutable` for immutable coming from ImmutableJS lib.

Comment: @Dan,: and you're absolutly right about this point: "At this point you would be better off profiling different implementations against your app, as the specifics can vary depending on your use case". Redux-Form forces me to implement good `shouldComponentUpdate()` that do not require using ImmutableJS.

Comment: Technically you can still use `react-addons-shallow-compare` even for ImmutableJS props. Many people do! It won’t bail out in some cases but it’s good enough and you can always go further if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I was also using a large Redux Store, and found that using the Immutable.js can make the accessing of the state complicated, e.g., nested2.getIn(['a', 'b', 'd']) vs nested2.a.b.d; What I really need is to make sure I don't mutate the state in my reducers, and still be able to check the equality using === in the shouldComponentUpdate() method.

I have created https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign to fulfill my requirements. It is a light weigh immutable helper, which supports immutability and allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object), so our React components can read the state as usual, e.g.,

```js
return newState.a.b.d === oldState.a.b.d;
```

Example,

```js
var iassign = require("immutable-assign");

var o1 = { a: { b: { c: [[{ d: 11, e: 12 }], [{ d: 21, e: 22 }]], c2: {} }, b2: {} }, a2: {} };

//
// Calling iassign() to push new item to o1.a.b.c[1]
//
var o2 = iassign(
  o1,
  function (o) { return o.a.b.c[1]; },  // get property to be updated 
  function (c) {                        // update select property
    c.push(101); 
    return c; 
  }
);


// o2.a.b.c[1][1] === 101
// o1 is not modified

// o2 !== o1
// o2.a !== o1.a
// o2.a.b !== o1.a.b
// o2.a.b.c !== o1.a.b.c
// o2.a.b.c[1] !== o1.a.b.c[1]

// o2.a2 === o1.a2
// o2.a.b2 === o1.a.b2
// o2.a.b.c2 === o1.a.b.c2
// o2.a.b.c[0] === o1.a.b.c[0]
// o2.a.b.c[0][0] === o1.a.b.c[0][0]
// o2.a.b.c[1][0] === o1.a.b.c[1][0]
```